# In Java finding numbers that are both a Triangle Number and a Star Number

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

This is the question I've been assigned:

> A so-called “star number”, s, is a number defined by the formula: 
>   s = 6n(n-1) + 1 
>   where n is the index of the star number. 
>       Thus the first six (i.e. for n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6) star numbers are: 1, 13, 37,
>    73, 121, 181
>
> In contrast a so-called “triangle number”, t, is the sum of the numbers from 1 to n: t = 1 + 2 + … + (n-1) + n. 
>   Thus the first six (i.e. for n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6) triangle numbers are:  1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21
>
> Write a Java application that produces a list of all the values of type int that are both star number and triangle numbers.
>
> When solving this problem you MUST write and use at least one function (such as `isTriangeNumber()` or `isStarNumber()` 
>   or `determineTriangeNumber()` or `determineStarNumber()`).  Also you MUST only use the formulas provided here to solve the problem.

tl;dr: Need to output values that are both Star Numbers and Triangle Numbers.

Unfortunately, I can only get the result to output the value '1' in an endless loop, even though I am incrementing by 1 in the while loop.

```
public class TriangularStars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n=1;            
    int starNumber = starNumber(n);
    int triangleNumber = triangleNumber(n);

    while ((starNumber<Integer.MAX_VALUE)&&(n<=Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        if ((starNumber==triangleNumber)&& (starNumber<Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                {
                    System.out.println(starNumber);
                }
        n++;
    }
  }


public static int starNumber( int n)
{
    int starNumber;
    starNumber= (((6*n)*(n-1))+1);
    return starNumber;

}
public static int triangleNumber( int n)
{
    int triangleNumber;
    triangleNumber =+ n;
    return triangleNumber;
}
```

}

Comment: The n you use for each method has to be different because one grows much faster than the other. use a starN and triangleN and increment the "n" which products a smaller number until they match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a skeleton. Finish the rest yourself:

Questions to ask yourself:

1. How do I make a Triangle number?
2. How do I know if something is a Star number?
3. Why do I only need to proceed until triangle is negative? How can triangle ever be negative?

Good luck!

```
public class TriangularStars {
  private static final double ERROR = 1e-7;

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int triangle = 0;
    for (int i = 0; triangle >= 0; i++) {
      triangle = determineTriangleNumber(i, triangle);
      if (isStarNumber(triangle)) {
        System.out.println(triangle);
      }
    }
  }

  public static boolean isStarNumber(int possibleStar) {
    double test = (possibleStar - 1) / 6.;
    int reduce = (int) (test + ERROR);
    if (Math.abs(test - reduce) > ERROR)
      return false;

    int sqrt = (int) (Math.sqrt(reduce) + ERROR);
    return reduce == sqrt * (sqrt + 1);
  }

  public static int determineTriangleNumber(int i, int previous) {
    return previous + i;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1
253
49141
9533161
1849384153
```

Comment: I believe this solution is incorrect, if you only go as far as Math.sqrt(Integer.MAX_VALUE), you are only testing as far as triangular(46340), which has a value of 1073720970. This is only ~1B, therefore not testing as far as the full range of 2.14B(Integer.MAX_VALUE). This leads to a failure to print the number 1849384153 which is both a star and triangular number.
If I have made a mistake please correct me, but as far as I can see, the assumption we only need to go as far as Math.sqrt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) is incorrect

Comment: You're correct, @AndrewB. It actually needs to be `Math.sqrt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) * Math.sqrt(2)`, but there's an easier way, which I've edited into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add new calls to `starNumber()` and `triangleNumber()` inside the loop.  You get the initial values but never re-call them with the updated `n` values.

As a first cut, I would put those calls immediatly following the n++, so

```
n++;
starNumber = starNumber(n);
triangleNumber = triangleNumber(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: When I do that, then I just get '1' as the result. Granted it's no longer an endless loop (so that's one problem solved), but there are no other results that I get.

Comment: See the third problem in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The question here is that "N" neednt be the same for both star and triangle numbers. So you can increase "n" when computing both star and triangle numbers, rather keep on increasing the triangle number as long as its less the current star number. Essentially you need to maintain two variable "n" and "m".

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you only call the `starNumber()` method once, outside the loop. (And the same with `triangleNumber()`.)

A secondary problem is that unless `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is a star number, your loop will run forever. The reason being that Java numerical operations overflow silently, so if your next star number would be bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, the result would just wrap around. You need to use `long`s to detect if a number is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

The third problem is that even if you put all the calls into the loop, it would only display star number/triangle number pairs that share the same `n` value. You need to have two indices in parallel, one for star number and another for triangle numbers and increment one or the other depending on which function returns the smaller number. So something along these lines:

```
while( starNumber and triangleNumber are both less than or equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
   while( starNumber < triangleNumber ) {
     generate next starnumber;         
   }
   while( triangleNumber < starNumber ) {
     generate next triangle number;
   }
   if( starNumber == triangleNumber ) {
     we've found a matching pair
   }
}
```

And the fourth problem is that your `triangleNumber()` method is wrong, I wonder how it even compiles.

Comment: Do you mean use longs instead of ints for every variable, and then convert to an int at the end?

Comment: You don't need to convert them to ints at all. just check if they're larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: How would I generate the nest starNumber in the while loop? Or the next triangleNumber? Should I call the function again?

Comment: Better than converting to long is to just check if it's less than 0. It won't go from a high positive, skip the entire negative, and become a low positive in one step. So if you have a negative, you know you've overflowed, and you know if you don't have a negative, you haven't overflowed yet: adding MAX + MAX yields -2. So if it's ever only a single add, you can safely just test for being negative to determine the existence of overflow.

Comment: How else? But I'd go with @durron597's answer if I were you. My answer is mostly about why your code isn't working, that answer gives you an idea of how to write it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think your methodology is flawed. You won't be able to directly make a method of `isStarNumber(n)` without, inside that method, testing every possible star number. I would take a slightly different approach: pre-computation.

first, find all the triangle numbers:

```
List<Integer> tris = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 2, t = 1; t > 0; i++) { // loop ends after integer overflow
    tris.add(t);
    t += i; // compute the next triangle value
}
```

we can do the same for star numbers:

consider the following -

```
star(n) = 6*n*(n-1) + 1 = 6n^2 - 6n + 1

therefore, by extension

star(n + 1) = 6*(n+1)*n + 1 = 6n^2 + 6n +1

and, star(n + 1) - star(n - 1), with some algebra, is 12n

star(n+1) = star(n) + 12* n
```

This leads us to the following formula

```
List<Integer> stars = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1, s = 1; s > 0; i++) {
    stars.add(s);
    s += (12 * i);
}
```

The real question is... do we really need to search every number? The answer is no! We only need to search numbers that are actually one or the other. So we could easily use the numbers in the stars (18k of them) and find the ones of those that are also tris!

```
for(Integer star : stars) {
    if(tris.contains(star)) 
        System.out.println("Awesome! " + star + " is both star and tri!");
}
```

I hope this makes sense to you. For your own sake, don't blindly move these snippets into your code. Instead, learn why it does what it does, ask questions where you're not sure. (Hopefully this isn't due in two hours!)

And good luck with this assignment.

Here's something awesome that will return the first 4 but not the last one. I don't know why the last won't come out. Have fun with this :

```
class StarAndTri2 {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        final double q2 = Math.sqrt(2);
        out(1);
        int a = 1;
        for(int i = 1; a > 0; i++) {
            a += (12 * i);
            if(x((int)(Math.sqrt(a)*q2))==a)out(a);
        }
    }
    static int x(int q) { return (q*(q+1))/2; }
    static void out(int i) {System.out.println("found: " + i);}
}
```